# StartDate - EndDate is same as EndDate - StartDate in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In general scenario

```
$a = 100;
$b = 150;
/*  
    Output of $a - $b = (100 – 150) = -50 (Negative value)
    Output of $b - $a = (150 – 100) = 50 (Positive value)
*/
```

I am trying to get difference between two dates using Carbon as below…

```
$start = Carbon::now(); 
$end = $start->copy()->addMinute(2);
echo $start->diffInSeconds($end); /* output is 120 */
echo $end->diffInSeconds($start); /* output is 120 */
```

**Question is why diffInSeconds returning same value in both cases?**
Might be I am missing something here.

And what should be correct method to achieve correct values.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: The difference is correct. Isn't it? Did you expect negative 120 in first case?

Comment: @nice_dev, yes I was expecting negative value, at least in 1 case. I got my answer as suggested below. I need to use 2nd parameter as false.

Comment: Actually, the difference is always a positive value that's why  default behavior is like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference):

> Each function below has a default first parameter which is the Carbon
> instance to compare to, or null if you want to use now(). The 2nd
> parameter again is optional and indicates if you want the return value
> to be the absolute value or a relative value that might have a -
> (negative) sign if the passed in date is less than the current
> instance. This will default to true, return the absolute value.

So to get negative values (where appropriate), set the optional second parameter to `false`.